# Restore .bak on MS SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

We have restore command which we can execute from command line.
I want to restore backup from Java class.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can run system commands from Java code.

The best way to do this is using [the `ProcessBuilder` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).